# Error: Attempted to access data(2,:); index out of bounds because size(data)=[1,7129]

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have a micro-array data of 38 row and 7130 columns. I am trying to read the data but keeping having the above error.

I debugged and found when I read the data, I have a 1x7129 instead of a 38x7130. I don't know why. My 7130th column contains letters while the rest of the data are numbers. Any idea why this is happening?

---

My file is in text tab delimited and here is my code for reading the file:

```
clear; 
fn=32; 
col=fn+1; 
cluster=2; 
num_eachClass=3564; 
row=num_eachClass*cluster; 
fid1 = fopen('data.txt', 'r'); 
txt_format=''; 
for t=1:col txt_format=[txt_format '%g ']; 
end 
data = fscanf(fid1,txt_format,[col row]); 
data = data'; fclose(fid1);
```

Comment: What is your file format and more important how do you read the data? Show your code and some data sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to read the data:

```
filename = 'yourfilename.txt';
fid = fopen(filename,'r');

% If you have a line with column headers use those 3 lines. Comment if not.
colnames = fgetl(fid);
colnames = textscan(colnames, '%s','delimiter','\t');
colnames = colnames{:};

% Reading the data
tsformat = [repmat('%f ',1,7129) '%s'];
datafromfile = textscan(fid,tsformat,'delimiter','\t','CollectOutput',1);
fclose(fid);

% Get the data from the cell array    
data = datafromfile{1};
labels = datafromfile{2};
```

---

**EDIT**
To separate your dataset to training and test, do something like this:

```
train_samp = 1:19;
test_samp = 20:38;
train_data = data(train_samp,:);
test_data = data(test_samp,:);
train_label = labels(train_samp);
test_label = labels(test_samp);
```

You can also separate samples randomly:

```
samp_num = size(data,1);
test_num = 19;
randorder = randperm(samp_num);
train_samp = randorder(test_num+1:samp_num);
test_samp = randorder(1:test_num);
```

I haven't done transposition `data = data';`.
If you have to, just switch row and column indexes in the above code:

```
train_data = data(:,train_samp);
test_data = data(:,test_samp);
```

Comment: i used your code but have errror: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.